# Design an algorithm to a specific version of Two-egg

Tags: algorithm

**Egg drop.** Suppose that you have an N-story building (with floors 1 through N) and plenty of eggs. An egg breaks if it is dropped from floor T or higher and does not break otherwise. Your goal is to devise a strategy to determine the value of T given the following limitations on the number of eggs and tosses:

- Version 0: 1 egg ≤T tosses.
- Version 1: ∼1lgN eggs and ∼1lgN tosses.
- Version 2: ∼lgT eggs and ∼2lgT tosses
- Version 3: 2 eggs and ∼2 √N tosses.
- **Version 4: 2 eggs and ≤c√T tosses for some fixed constant c.**

This is a Job Interview Question provided by online course Algorithms,Part I(Princeton).I've already known the general solution for how to find minimum tosses needed with 2 eggs, and I can understand version 0 through version 3.

My question is how to design the algorithm for version 4. I don't have any idea even with the hint.
The hint given by the course is :**1+2+3+…+t∼1/2*t^2. Aim for c=2√2.**

Answer (score 1):

**The meaning of hint given in Version 4 is :**

divide N to many `blocks`, such as:

- 1st floor in `block` 1, i.e., 1 floor in `block 1`.
- 2nd and 3rd floor in `block 2`, i.e., 2 floors in `block 2`.
- 4th, 5th, and 6th in `block 3`, i.e., 3 floors in `block 3`.

...

- There are `m` floors in `block m`. Suppose that floor `T` in this block.

Then, throw egg form first floor in `block m` to last floor in `block m` to find `T`.

Java Code (With Chinese comments):

`

/**

```
* Ex 1.4.24

* EggsDrop问题

* ~2logF投掷, ~logF鸡蛋

* @param N

*       楼层高度

* @param F

*       鸡蛋恰好摔碎的楼层

* @return 程序猜到的楼层数
*/

private static int eggsDrop3(int N, int F) {

    //debug...

    int debugCnt = 0;

    int debugEggs = 0;

    //区块的左端点相对于一楼的offset
    int leftOffset = 0;

    //区块的长度
    int length = 1;

    //result
    int f = 0;

    //初始第一个区块的左右offset都是0, 因为在第一个区块只有一层楼
    while (leftOffset + length <= N) {
        //leftOffset + legth表示当前区块的右端点
        if (leftOffset + length >= F) {
            debugEggs++;
            debugCnt++;
            //从区块左端点开始遍历
            int last = leftOffset + 1;
            while (last++ < F)
                debugCnt++;
            debugEggs++;
            f = last - 1;
            break;
        } 

        debugCnt++;
        leftOffset += length;
        length++;
    }

    o("tosses: " + debugCnt + ", eggs: " + debugEggs);

    return f;
}
```

`

Here is my github project for *Algorithms 4th Ed.* (In Chinese):

[My solutions to Exercise in *Algorithms 4th Ed.*](https://github.com/DCMMC/Java/blob/master/Algorithms/tk/dcmmc/fundamentals/Exercises/AnalysisOfAlgorithms.java)

Answer (score 0):

Proceed as follows:

Throw the first egg from the first floor, then from the second, from the fourth, from the seventh and so on. I.e. the difference of successive floors increases by one each step.

The number of throws you need to pass `T` is

```
n1 = -1/2 + roundup( sqrt(1/4 + 2T) )
```

Then use the second egg to make your way linearly from the last check point to T. This will take you `n2` tosses:

```
n2 = T - Sum { i from 1 to n1 - 1 } (i)
```

You will see that `n2` is also `O(sqrt(T))`. So, the total number of tosses `n1 + n2` is in `O(sqrt(T))` which is what you wanted.

Comment: Why the number of throws you need to pass T is:
n1 = -1/2 + roundup( sqrt(1/4 + 2T) ).
I think n1 would be lgT+1

Comment: No, it is the equation `Sum {i from 1 to n1} (i) >= T` solved for `n1`. As the hint says, there is a quadratic dependency between `n1` and `T`, not an exponential one like if you would increase the step size by multiplying a constant.

Comment: OK, then we are throwing the first egg from 1st,(+1)2nd,(+2)4th,(+3)7th,(+4)11th...right?

Comment: Thanks! I got exactly `2sqrt(2T)` at the end.
floor(n)=corresponding floor in nth throw=`1+1+2+...+(n-1)=1/2*n^2-1/2*n+1`
1.`n1>=T-->n1=sqrt(2T)` for T not very small.
2.Instead of `n2 = T - Sum { i from 1 to n1 - 1 }(i)`, I use` n2=length of the interval between floor(n1-1) and floor(n1), so `n2=sqrt(2T)`.
3.Add up we get `~2sqrt(2T)`